# Why is Postgres double-quoting the first function identifier when I set a default function for a column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql

I have a legacy table with a default expression in a Rails project. This expression picks a random four-digit number and converts it to a string. During my tests I have been typing this exact statement into psql to set the default expression:

```sql
alter table owners alter column signing_code set default 
substring(to_char(((random() * ((10000 - 1))::double precision) + 
(1)::double precision), '0000'::text), '....$'::text);
```

Then when I do `\d owners` this is what Postgres has decided is my actual default expression:

```
default "substring"(to_char(((random() * ((10000 - 1))::double 
precision) + (1)::double precision), '0000'::text), '....$'::text)
```

Notice the double quotes around the first function identifier `substring`. This causes two problems with Rails schema dumps/loads:

1. When dumping the schema to db/schema.rb, invalid Ruby is produced because the double quotes are not escaped
2. Even if you correctly escape the quotes by hand, when loading the schema back into the database, Rails incorrectly sets the entire expression as a default string value, not an expression (i.e. it surrounds the expression with single quotes)

Is there a way to get Postgres to not double quote the first function in the nested function call in my case? That would be a good workaround, otherwise I'll submit a bug with the Rails project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the `substring` function gets double quoted doesn't really matter, the two expressions are functionally equivalent. PostgreSQL will parse the default expression and then save the parsed version and during this process, the `substring` identifier gets double quoted. You can see similar things happen if you add a CHECK constraint like this:

```
check (c in (1, 2, 3))
```

Doing a `\d` on a table with that constraint will give you:

```
CHECK (c = ANY (ARRAY[1, 2, 3]))
```

PostgreSQL translates the `in` expression to an equivalent `= ANY` expression because that's what it wants to work with internally. The two expressions are functionally equivalent.

The real problem is that ActiveRecord doesn't know what to do with a default expression that is more complex than a single literal value. AR makes an invalid assumption about what defaults look like and then blindly plods along making a mess.

When you're dealing with anything beyond the simplest DDL SQL your best bet is to use `db/structure.sql` instead of `db/schema.rb`. `structure.sql` uses the database's native dump/restore tools so it will understand and preserve everything the database knows about.

Switching to `structure.sql` is pretty simple:

1. Update `config/application.rb` to use the right format:

   ```
   config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
   ```
2. Dump your `structure.sql` using the `db:structure:dump` rake task.
3. Remove `db/schema.rb` from your source tree and revision control.
4. Add `db/structure.sql` to revision control.
5. Retrain your fingers to use different rake tasks for dumping and restoring the schema:

   - `db:structure:dump` instead of `db:schema:dump`.
   - `db:structure:load` instead of `db:schema:load`.

I always start with `structure.sql` as `schema.rb` is too limited for how I want to work with my databases.